# Search/Text Field in OSX Menu Bar Application

Tags: swift, macos

I have seen this example in Obj-C development for OSX, but I was wondering if it is possible to insert a Search Field or a Text Field into a Menu Bar application using Swift.

Here is an example of an application, but in Obj-C

[S/S Example App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAJWS.png)

Answer (score 0):

Yes,follow along this [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/98178/os-x-tutorial-menus-popovers-menu-bar-apps). It shows how to use `NSPopover`. You can use `NSPopover`'s view outlet to customize your user interface, which is a `NSTextField` in your case.